# Log Redis monitor command results?

Tags: logging, redis, server

So when I use `redis-cli monitor` command, I get a huge bunch of text that does not even fit the console.

Does it get logged somewhere? Or is it somehow possible to write all these data in some text file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well I didn't know about simple command line that logs console output into text file:

```
redis-cli [-h `host`] [-p `port`] [-a `auth`] monitor > redislog.txt
```

Comment: You can also do something like `redis-cli monitor | tee redislog.txt` and get output to both console and file. In any case, it is unix question, rather than redis.

Comment: it seems that we must run it as a redis-cli param only and when selecting our ports like : redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6381 monitor > log.txt